# Fourier transform of attenuated propagating pulse

Tags: fourier-transform

I am studying the optical properties of a medium by looking at how a Gaussian pulse is deformed as it propagates through the medium. The initial Gaussian pulse signal and Fourier transform are :

\begin{align}
E(0, t)&= E_0 e^{-\left(\frac{t-t_0}{\tau_0}\right)^2}\cos\big(2\pi\nu_0 (t-t_0 )+\phi_0\big) \\
\hat E(0,\nu) &= \hat E_0 e^{-\left(\frac{\nu-\nu_0}{\Delta\nu}\right)^2}e^{j(\nu t_0 + \phi_0)}
\end{align}
where $\pi\tau_0\Delta\nu = 1$ relates the width of the spectral and temporal pulse.

I am looking at the propagation of this pulse in a medium which is dispersive  (the frequencies do not propagate at the same phase speed $\beta(\nu)/2\pi\nu$ hence they accumulate a phase shift from one another) and dissipative (the frequencies are attenuated $\alpha(\nu)$ as they propagate).

To determine the properties $\alpha(\nu)$ and $\beta(\nu)$ of this medium, I simply perform the Fourier transform $\hat E(z_i,\nu)$ of the pulse signal $E(z_i,t)$ at different points $z_i$ and compare them to the original spectrum $\hat E(0,\nu)$ through :

\begin{align}
\alpha(\nu) &=\frac{\log\left(\displaystyle\frac{\lvert\hat E(z_i,\nu)\rvert}{\lvert\hat E(0,\nu)\rvert}\right)}{z_i} \\
\beta(\nu) &= \frac{\phi (z_i,\nu)-\phi (0,\nu)}{z_i}
\end{align}
where $\phi(\nu)$ is the phase of the complex Fourier transform.

Testing this method with a known material surprisingly provides similar results but with additional ripples.

[image: Measured dissipation $\alpha^{num}$ of a medium whose theoretical dissipation should be $\alpha^{th}$]

**I really do not manage to figure out what I should do to get rid of the ripples or if these ripples are normal.**

I can provide plots of the Fourier transforms and signals of the pulses if necessary.

Comment: These plots will indeed be necessary, as well as information about your sampling resolution and total scan range.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Actually the error was coming from reflection from a PML in my numerical solver. The Fourier Transform of an attenuated pulse can indeed be used to accurately determine the dispersive properties of the material. The sampling resolution was 200 points per unit time(where $\nu_0=0.25$) and sampling range was 40000 points.